# Beginner Rails 3: Am I doing this 'create' method right?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Product` model that `belongs_to` a `User` and to a `Category`. In the `new` product form, I have only fields for Name (text), Category (select) and Price (text).

This is how I created the select field for category in `products/new.html.haml`:

```
= f.collection_select :category, Category.all, :id, :name
```

In `ProductsController`, I thought I'd only need to do this:

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(params[:product])
  if @product.save
    # do something
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

But I ended up needing to add code to load the Category object and to transform the monetary representation of the price (which is locale-dependent) to decimal. So this is what I got working:

```
def create
  params[:product][:category] = Category.find(params[:product][:category])
  # to_decimal is declared as a private method in ProductsController
  # and returns a decimal number or nil if the price is invalid
  params[:product][:price] = to_decimal(params[:product][:price])
  @product = Product.new(params[:product])
  if @product.save
    # do something
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

So my questions are:

**1)** Is there a way to make Rails load the Category automatically?

**2)** Am I doing the price "formatting" correctly? It seems like it should be in the model, but I couldn't make it work past the controller.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a rule in Rails convention called `skinny controller - fat model`.

You don't need any conversion to decimal, consider adding validation to your model:

```
validates :price, :numericality => true, :presence => true
```

That means your price have to be a number and cannot be empty.

What about category?
Add field `category_id` to your `Product` table, and in models put:

```
# product.rb
belongs_to :category
# category.rb
has_many :products
```

Show us your form please, and remember this page as your friend:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think your products table needs a column (integer) called 'category_id'. This way, your select should work without the additional controller code. As for the price, there should be a way to accept a decimal from the params hash, but I would need to see your form I think.